# using the arrows function to add confidence limits stored in a dataframe to a barplot

Tags: r

I'm sure this is a simple problem for most of you :) I have looked around the R help pages and on here and I know what the function is that I need (arrows I think) but I just don't understand how to use it. So my question is:

I have a dataframe (data) with the results of an experiment which I have simplified to this:

```
treatment   y   lower_limit_CI  upper_limit_CI
1   0.13284413  0.1224  0.1438
2   0.263072558 0.2458  0.2809
3   0.234218546 0.217   0.2521
4   0.394980185 0.3702  0.4201
5   0.474533107 0.4457  0.5035
6   0.583333333 0.5526  0.6136
```

I have drawn a barplot of the data like so:

```
plot <- barplot(data$y)
```

and I know that I now need the function arrows (yes?) to add the confidence limits also stored in my dataframe to the plot.

Can someone please show me how to use arrows to get the correct info. from my dataframe? I have tried this on the advice of someone:

```
arrows(plot, data$y - data$lower_limit_CI,
   plot, data$y + data$upper_limit_CI,
   code=3, angle=90, length =0.1)
```

which gives giant bars which are obviously incorrect. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Every time you put a confidence interval on a barplot, a statistician gets wings. That being said, here's an out of the box solution: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that instead of `barplot` and `arrows` functions, you use the much more flexible and powerful [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) package. Here's how the `ggplot`, `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar` functions can be used to create a barchart with confidence interval:

```
ggplot(data, aes(treatment, y, fill=1:6)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data$lower_limit_CI, ymax=data$upper_limit_CI), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted - thanks! I have ordered the ggplot2 book which I am still waiting on - in the meantime could you help me a little further by showing me how to have all of the bars labelled rather than just 2,4 and 6? I tried a few things but mostly succeeded in messing up the plot! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I figured it out - use scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 6, 1)) for anyone else who wants to know. Cheers!